# Transfer records

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a datagridview with 100 records

When I select a record

record go to the Datagridview form2

Then when I came back to form1

And others chose a record

It also goes to form2, but there is also the previous recession

Want datagridview in  form2 remains constant

I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: I want to do transfer Record Form2 from form1

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a Form2 variable in form1 which point to form2: `Form2 Frm2;`
2. Define a public DataTable in Form2: `Public DataTable Dt;`
3. Initilize Frm2 and dt in your form load event:

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     this.Frm2 = new Form2();
     this.Frm2.Dt = new DataTable();
   }
   ```
4. Here's where it gets done:

   ```
       public void AddRowInDataTable(int SelectedIndex)
   {
       //Add the columns
       DataColumn col = null;
       //For each columns in the datagridveiw add a new column to data table
       foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
       {
           col = new DataColumn(dgvCol.Name);
           if (!Frm2.dt.Columns.Contains(dgvCol.Name))
               Frm2.dt.Columns.Add(col);
       }
       //Add the selected row from the datagridview
       DataRow row = null;
       row = Frm2.dt.Rows.Add();
       foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
       {
           row[column.Index] = dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[column.Index].Value;
       }
   }
   ```
5. handle `OnCellClick` event of form1's dataGridView1:

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
    AddRowInDataTable(e.RowIndex);
    Frm2.ShowDialog();  
   }
   ```